# Transpose the data in a column every nth rows in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape, transpose

For a research project, I need to process every individual's information from the website into an excel file. I have copied and pasted everything I need from the website onto a single column in an excel file, and I loaded that file using PANDAS. However, I need to present each individual's information horizontally instead of vertically like it is now. 
For example, this is what I have right now. I only have one column of unorganized data.

```
df= pd.read_csv("ior work.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

Data:

```
0 Andrew
1 School of Music
2 Music: Sound of the wind
3 Dr. Seuss
4 Dr.Sass
5 Michelle
6 School of Theatrics
7 Music: Voice
8 Dr. A
9 Dr. B
```

I want transpose every 5 lines to organize the data into this organizational format; the labels below are labels of the columns.

```
Name School Music Mentor1 Mentor2
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If no data are missing, you can use [`numpy.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
print (np.reshape(df.values,(2,5)))
[['Andrew' 'School of Music' 'Music: Sound of the wind' 'Dr. Seuss'
  'Dr.Sass']
 ['Michelle' 'School of Theatrics' 'Music: Voice' 'Dr. A' 'Dr. B']]

print (pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.values,(2,5)), 
                    columns=['Name','School','Music','Mentor1','Mentor2']))
       Name               School                     Music    Mentor1  Mentor2
0    Andrew      School of Music  Music: Sound of the wind  Dr. Seuss  Dr.Sass
1  Michelle  School of Theatrics              Music: Voice      Dr. A    Dr. B
```

More general solution with generating `length` of new `array` by [`shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html) divide by number of columns:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.values,(df.shape[0] / 5,5)), 
                    columns=['Name','School','Music','Mentor1','Mentor2']))
       Name               School                     Music    Mentor1  Mentor2
0    Andrew      School of Music  Music: Sound of the wind  Dr. Seuss  Dr.Sass
1  Michelle  School of Theatrics              Music: Voice      Dr. A    Dr. B
```

Thank you [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761366/transpose-the-data-in-a-column-every-nth-rows-in-pandas/39762293?noredirect=1#comment66820514_39762293) for another solution:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 5), 
                    columns=['Name','School','Music','Mentor1','Mentor2']))
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 5), columns=['Name','School','Music','Mentor1','Mentor2']))`

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael and @piRSquared!