# Transpose every nth rows from one column to multiple columns using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Can someone suggest me how to transpose every nth rows from one column to multiple columns using pandas. Assume that I have a dataframe that contains the following: -

| index | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 275 |
| 1 | 0.81 |
| 2 | 388 |
| 3 | 2.26 |
| 4 | 275 |
| 5 | 0.93 |
| 6 | 447 |
| 7 | 2.60 |
| 8 | 275 |
| 9 | 1.05 |
| 10 | 500 |
| 11 | 2.91 |
| 12 | 275 |
| 13 | 1.15 |
| 14 | 549 |
| 15 | 3.20 |

The desired output: -

| index | "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 275 | 0.81 | 388 | 2.26 |
| 1 | 275 | 0.93 | 447 | 2.60 |
| 2 | 275 | 1.05 | 500 | 2.91 |
| 3 | 275 | 1.15 | 549 | 3.20 |

I tried `pd.wide_to_long` but it didnt work.

```
df3 = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames= '0', i='index', j='id')
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at `numpy.reshape`

Comment: Help the OP @Ch3steR

Comment: @sammywemmy I'm on mobile rn. Can't write an answer. `np.reshape` would fail sometimes though if `shape` is say `7` and OP wants `2` columns, that would raise an error. To make it work padding with `fill_value` would work but OP hasn't specified anything about it tho. Looks someone answered already ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose the data in a column every nth rows in PANDAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761366/transpose-the-data-in-a-column-every-nth-rows-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered as on another question:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 4), 
                    columns=['A','B','C','D']))
```

check here:

[Transpose the data in a column every nth rows in PANDAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761366/transpose-the-data-in-a-column-every-nth-rows-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `np.reshape()` function.
please follow given steps:

Step 1: convert your dataframe column data into a numpy array

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(df[0]
```

Step 2: then reshape this array data into your desired number of columns

`array2 = np.reshape(arr, (4, 4)) # here (4, 4) are the number of rows and columns`

Step 3: make a new data frame of your reshaped array

`df3 = pd.DataFrame(array2, columns = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'})`

Now your old data frame is changed into your desired number of columns's data frame.